# Directory issues

Tags: php

At the moment I am in the following

```
/public_html/v3/football/admin/new.php
```

Inside that new.php, i want to include a file in the following place

```
/public_html/v3/include/session.php
```

I am having problems trying to include this, can someone help? please!

Comment: What are your problems when trying to include that file?

Comment: I dont know how to reference it, how to get to that from the first one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require '../../include/session.php';
```

More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

You should define a base dir constant in a bootstrap type file...

```
// If >= PHP 5.3
define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__);

// Otherwise
define('BASE_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

And include files like so...

```
include BASE_DIR . 'admin/new.php';
```

This is handy, so you shouldn't have to traverse up directories - just supply paths relative to that constant.

If you insist, you should be able to include that `session.php` with

```
require '/public_html/v3/include/session.php';
// or
require '../../include/session.php';
```

Comment: I am trying to include the session file in the new file. How would I do that? I already have a constants page so this wouldnt be difficult to include.